# Fundamentals of character scanning from user in C

Tags: c

Hi this question might look kinda stupid, but I am facing some serious lack of fundamentals here which i cannot figure out. This is a very simple code for scanning four characters but it wont work properly. This is an extract from a larger program, but this is where I am facing the problem. Can anyone point out where the blunder is being made?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
{

    char a, b, c, d;
    printf("Enter the value of a\n");
    scanf("%c", &a);
    if(a == 'Y')
    {

        printf("Enter if this question is stupid or no Y/N\n");
        scanf("%c", &b);

    }
    else
    {

        printf("This is such a big waste of time");

    }

    printf("Enter the value of c\n");
    scanf("%c", &c);

    if(c == 'Y')
    {

        printf("Enter if I am stupid or no? Y/N\n");
        scanf("%c", &d);

    }
    else
    {

        printf("I will go mad soon\n");

    }

}
```

Comment: I think the problem might be in the implementation of the "if" statements. Tried with getchar() also.

Comment: What problem you are facing

Comment: The (arguably) only correct way to deal with user input is to `fgets()` a complete line (ENTER and all) then parse the line (with eg `sscanf()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is possible that you have problems because of newline character. Try using

```
 scanf(" %c", &var)
```

**Note**: My original answer was wrong but accepted, I copied this solution from @teppic.

Comment: @teppic You are right it really does not work well. What is the best way to fix this, should I delete the answer?

Comment: You don't need to delete it, you're right about the problem. Just fix the solution (what I put in my answer works fine).

Comment: Yes I know but that was your answer not mine :).

Comment: @Martinsos - that's fine :)

Answer (score 2):

The `%c` specifier tells `scanf` to read one character only. When you type a character and press enter, you're providing two. So the next call already has a character to read.

In order to get this work properly you need to skip any whitespace before you read a character. Change each call like this:

`scanf(" %c", &a)`

Now any previous newline you entered will be skipped.

Comment: This is the best solution in my opinion, since it also discards other white space characters apart from '\n'.

Comment: @Lundin - scanf will treat all whitespace the same anyway, it doesn't distinguish between them

Comment: If you type '\n' it will only discard line feed, yes?

Comment: @Lundin Nope, it will discard spaces and tabs too. (That's why the accepted answer is wrong -- scanf will block forever, ignoring whitespace, until you enter something else).

Comment: Aha. Can't say I've tried it myself, the few times I use scanf, I always use the " %c" notation. (I also believe that the printf/scanf functions are the most catastrophically poor library functions ever written, but maybe that's just me.)

Comment: Normally scanf will ignore all whitespace completely (e.g. "%d%d" is the same as "%d \n  %d"), but it doesn't with %c.

Answer (score -1):

You are not flushing your buffer after scanning the character, when You enter a character and press ENTER then in next scan your ENTER is treated as a character that's why it is skipping the second scan. Use any one of these __fpurge(stdin), fpurge(stdin) after each scan, whatever works on your system. It will work.

Comment: [`fflush()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush): _If the given stream is of the input type, then the behavior of the function is undefined._

Comment: `fflush` is only guaranteed to work on output streams. Implementations may allow it on input streams, but it's not standard.

Comment: @ Lundin I apologize for my mistake, but I'm quite sure about __fpurge and fpurge

Comment: fpurge() isn't standard C though.